# Change the values in a tuple in a list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a two-dimensional list containing three-element tuple.

```
image = [[(15, 103, 255), (0, 3, 19)],[(22, 200, 1), (8, 8, 8)],[(0, 0, 0), (5, 123, 19)]]
```

I want to add one to each element.

```
def get_elements(image):
    for i in range(len(image)-1) :
        m = image[i]
        for j in range(len(m)-1) :
            n = image[j]
            for k in range(len(n)-1) :
                ans = image[i][j][k]
                ans = ans+1
                return ans
```

This code just adds one to the first element and returns 15 + 1 = 16.   I want it to give:

```
image = [[(16, 104, 256), (1, 4, 20)],[(23, 201, 2), (9, 9, 9)],[(1, 1, 1), (6, 124, 20)]]
```

Answer (score 10):

Tuples are immutable. You can't modify them directly, so the best bet is to generate a new list with new tuples.

```
>>> image
[[(15, 103, 255), (0, 3, 19)], [(22, 200, 1), (8, 8, 8)], [(0, 0, 0), (5, 123, 19)]]
>>> [[(r+1,g+1,b+1) for r,g,b in row] for row in image]
[[(16, 104, 256), (1, 4, 20)], [(23, 201, 2), (9, 9, 9)], [(1, 1, 1), (6, 124, 20)]]
```

This uses two nested list comprehensions. The outer one loops over each row, yielding a new replacement row each iteration (here denoted `[...]`):

```
[[...] for row in image]
```

The inner one loops over the pixels in each row, yielding new tuples with modified RGB values.

```
[(r+1,g+1,b+1) for r,g,b in row]
```

Comment: What if i want to add two functions, set_bit(pixel value,bits,0) and char_to_bits(message) in the nested list comprehension.

Comment: Is is possible to do this with a for loop ?

Answer (score 4):

If you are doing image manipulation, you should consider `numpy`

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> image = np.array([[(15, 103, 255), (0, 3, 19)],[(22, 200, 1), (8, 8, 8)],[(0, 0, 0), (5, 123, 19)]])
>>> image + 1
array([[[ 16, 104, 256],
        [  1,   4,  20]],

       [[ 23, 201,   2],
        [  9,   9,   9]],

       [[  1,   1,   1],
        [  6, 124,  20]]])
```

`numpy` already has this common sense definition of adding `1` to an array